# How to loop and update BAO objects

Tags: database, developer

I was trying to be down with the cool kids and use DB_Object models for a looped database update. I've found somethning I thought should work, but doesn't so I must be doing/understanding something wrong.

```
$bao = new CRM_Some_BAO();
$bao->hair = 'long';
$bao->find();
while ($bao->fetch()) {
  $bao->message = 'cool hair, ' . $bao->name;
  $bao->save();
}
```

I'd thought that something like the above would find everyone with long hair and set a message to 'cool hair, `<name>`'

But actually what happens is that only the first match gets processed. I've also tried `clone($bao)` and updating the clone, but it's still same.

What's the [DB_Object](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.db-dataobject.update.php) way of achieving such a pattern?

I'm currently just resorting to standard SQL.

Comment: Since you know they already exist I might try it with update() instead of save(). And while I've never tried using DB_DATAOBJECT_WHEREADD_ONLY, it seems like you might be able to omit the loop entirely and pass that param to update to be more efficient, since then it says it will do a batch update to make them all "cool" at once.

Comment: @Demerit thanks. In trying to keep the pseudo code short I should have been clear that each update is actually unique.

Comment: Ok got it. Update() alone might still work?

Comment: @Demerit You're right, `update()` works, but CiviCRM's `save()` method does more, it also runs hooks etc. I'm looking for a generic, CiviCRM-way to do such jobs.